# Backorder status of product

Tags: product, magento2.3, order-success-page, backorder

I need to display backorder status of products in success page.
we have 3 status and each product show its status.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To show the product status on Success page you can get the value from quote. Either you can use extension attribute as well.

If you have backorder item in cart you can simply get its information on success.phtml file by using this code

```
<?php
$lid = $this->getOrderId();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($lid);
$items=$order->getAllItems();
foreach($items as $_item):
   $_product = 
$objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProductId());
        echo 'ID: '.$_product->getId().'<br />';
        echo 'Name: '.$_product->getName().'<br />';
        echo 'Sku: '.$_product->getSku().'<br />';
        echo 'Quantity: '.$_item->getQtyOrdered().'<br />';
        echo 'Price: '.$_item->getPrice().'<br />';
        echo "<br />"; 

endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response, but can you be more clear?

Comment: I have edit the answer.

Comment: from your code where is backorder status please?

Comment: You can add this code in success.phtml to get the backorder product..$obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  
$stockRegistry = $obj->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');
$stockitem = $stockRegistry->getStockItem($_product->getId(),$_product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
echo "Backorder: "; echo $stockitem->getBackorders(); echo '<br>';

Comment: If you find my answer helpful. Please mark it useful. Thanks

Comment: the use of object manager is a bad practice

Comment: You can add this class as dependency manager Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface.